# App store replace native ios app with xamarin app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store

I have an app on the app store developed natively. The app uses local storage on the device. I have now developed a new version of it using Xamarin which uses local storage too. For it to work properly, when I run the new Xamarin app, I need to physically delete the app from the device to install the new version. The question is that when I now submit this version (Xamarin Forms) to the store I know that the app will be replaced on the users' device but what is going to happen to the local storage part? Or will it download as a new app with a new/separate icon - like having 2 apps on the device?

Comment: If it has the same bundle id, it is an app update.

Answer (score 0):

The local storage will be preserved. If you have to delete the local storage before the new app can run, you need to update the native app and delete the storage when the app is running.

Comment: To do an update on the live app is not / can not be done. Will just use the same bundle ID but make sure not to use the same storage path.